# how do I initialize 0 to both constructors?

Tags: java

h I assign the value of token count to 0, but it seems not working. and I do not know what is wrong with my code. I think my code works but I just don't know how to make the token count in the output to be 0. I ran the code in NetBeans, but the output is "Status true
Expected: true,
Token count: 2,
Expected: 2,
Can count: 18,
Expected: 8" AND I am using Java.

```
public class VendingMachine {
public int canCount;
public int tokenCount;
VendingMachine() {
    canCount = 10;
   tokenCount = 0;
}
VendingMachine(int cans) {
    canCount = cans;
   tokenCount = 0;
}
public void add(int cans) {
    canCount = canCount + cans;
}
public boolean insertToken() {
    if (canCount <= 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        canCount = canCount - 1;
        tokenCount = tokenCount + 1;
    }
    return true;
}
public int getCanCount() {
    return canCount;
}
public int getTokenCount() {
    return tokenCount;
}
```

}

AND here is my Tester code.

```
public class VendingMachineTester {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VendingMachine machine = new VendingMachine();
    machine.add(10);
    boolean status;
    machine.insertToken();
    status = machine.insertToken();
    System.out.println("Status " + status);
    System.out.println("Expected: true");
    System.out.print("Token count: ");
    System.out.println(machine.getTokenCount());
    System.out.println("Expected: 2");
    System.out.print("Can count: ");
    System.out.println(machine.getCanCount());
    System.out.println("Expected: 8");
}
```

}

Comment: Please move your code and everything to here instead of putting a link

Comment: public class VendingMachine {

    public int canCount;
    public int tokenCount;

    VendingMachine() {
        canCount = 10;
       tokenCount = 0;
    }

    VendingMachine(int cans) {
        canCount = cans;
       tokenCount = 0;
    }

    public void add(int cans) {
        canCount = canCount + cans;
    }

    public boolean insertToken() {
        if (canCount <= 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            canCount = canCount - 1;
            tokenCount = tokenCount + 1;
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: public int getCanCount() {
        return canCount;
    }

    public int getTokenCount() {
        return tokenCount;
    }

}

Comment: Edit your question and insert your code there, it's not readable in a comment...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" What tests did you run? What's the output?

Comment: `javascript` > `java`

Comment: .Java != Javascript. They're two entirely different languages. They're not the same just because they start with the same letters, any more than a *car* and a *carrot* are the same because they both start with *car*. Add just the tag for the language you're actually using. If you don't know which of the two you're using, stop trying to write code until you figure it out.

Comment: What's your `main` method looks like? Add input and expected output

Comment: I'm going to guess in your `main` method you created a `VendingMachine` with 20 cans (or 10 cans and `add(10)` cans) then `insertToken()`x2. There's your output.

Comment: It's because of `machine.add(10)`. Either delete it or rewrite your expected count.

Comment: Why do you expect `tokenCount` to be 0 in first place?

Comment: here is my teacher's requirement for the code:Provide two constructors for the VendingMachine class:
1) A default constructor, VendingMachine(), that initializes the vending machine with
10 soda cans
2) A constructor, VendingMachine(int cans), that initializes the vending machine
with the given number of cans
Both constructors should initialize the token count to 0.

Comment: It does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what correction should I make in order to let the token count to be 0.

Comment: In what scenario? If you're trying to simulate a vending machine, I guess each can should have a price, and then when you insert tokens it accumulates them until it reached that price. Then you'd zeroize the tokens number. Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct for your teacher's requirements so far. Constructors effectively create an Object. In this case you have 2 constructors `VendingMachine()` and `VendingMachine(int cans)` both of which in their respective code initialize `tokenCount` to 0.

Walking through your Tester line by line

```
VendingMachine machine = new VendingMachine();
```

This constructor creates a new `VendingMachine` called `machine` with `canCount` of 10 and `tokenCount` of 0. As you can see here your `tokenCount` is 0 it only changes later when you call `machine.insertToken()`.

```
machine.add(10);
```

This "adds" 10 cans to `machine` making the `canCount` now 20. `tokenCount` is still at 0

```
boolean status;
```

This creates a local variable called `status`.

```
machine.insertToken();
```

This "inserts" a "token" which turns the `canCount` to 19 and `tokenCount` to 1.

```
status = machine.insertToken();
```

This "inserts" a "token" and stores `true` to `status` and turns `canCount` to 18 and `tokenCount` to 2.

Naturally your `tokenCount` is going to be 2 because you called `insertToken()` twice. However you need to change your expected output for can count or remove the `add(10)`. This is rather trivial programming. I would consider looking into how to use the debugger as it really helps see what your code is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me cuz I just started to learn Java Language, so most of the time I just ask stupid questions. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome. If you think I successfully answered your question please be sure to accept the answer.